# Angular2 Kendo-Datepicker - Input as custom text

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-datepicker

Is it possible to have a kendo-datepicker without 'sections' (ddMMyyyy, ... - [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z0oO.png)), write custom strings to input without limitations and then format it ?

It was possible in kendo datepicker for JQuery but i dont see any option for that in kendo datepicker for Angular.

I tried to set FormatSettings.inputFormat to empty string, null, ... but nothing worked for me.